# Verifying gpg keys through script

Tags: bash, nginx, installation, centos

I am installing a package that needs gpg key verification check, i am able to verify those keys interactively but when i try to install the package through bash script i have to provide yum install  -y which skips the gpg key check .
I am installing `nginx` by adding repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo through these [instructions](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#:%7E:text=7BD9%20BF62%2C-,and%20if%20so%2C%20accept%20it.,-Debian)
When i am manually installing there is a prompt coming to check gpg key verification then i press enter but how does it match gpg key if i install nginx with `-y` . I don't know if it is checking or not. How can i confirm this if i install nginx through script after adding this repo , it verifies gpg?

I tried to install Nginx through script and expecting to verify gpg keys